# How to calculate the maximum number of concentric polygons from a given set of points?

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, convex-hull

Given a set of points we have to find the maximum number of simple polygons which all lie inside one another (Basically be kind of concentric) .

And it is not important to select all points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build convex hull for all points.

Remove points belonging to the hull.

Repeat for the next layer and so on ("onion peeling" approach)

[image]

Note there is `O(nlogn)` algorithm for building all convex layers cited [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_layers)

`Chazelle, Bernard (1985), "On the convex layers of a planar set", IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory, 31 (4): 509–517,`

Comment: And how will you do it if there's one more condition added that the points inside the hull have to belong to some polygon, then how will you approach it ?

Comment: Your question does not contain additional conditions. But seems this approach provides that all points belong to some hull polygon.

Comment: Yes, thank you sir for your very insightful approach. And just in case you have any idea regarding the additional constraint please tell us.

Comment: This solution always assigns all points to hulls, but I think it's true that you can never do better by omitting some points.